# How do I deal with ties when using rank-based normalizing transforms, e.g. Blom?

Tags: statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, overdispersion

I would like to transform heavily skewed data with range (-Inf, Inf) and heavily zero-inflated into a form suitable for using GLMs for significance testing.  Zero-inflation precludes the effective use of standard blom-family transforms (e.g. Blom, Elfving, etc) because they require data not to have ties.  It occurs to me that I can randomly break ties and fit an *ensemble* of glms on the resulting sampled datasets, and then average the significance result.  Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Is there any theory on normalizing copula transforms for continuous data with ties?  I can't find anything?
2. Does this bootstrap-driven correction make sense to folks?  Would it lose statistical power?

Someone has proposed that I run a Wilcoxon test.  That doesn't work for me for two reasons:

1. I need to run some multivariate fits and
2. Wilcoxon will heavily extrapolate the significance test by excluding 0s from ranks, which is roughly 2/3 of the measurements (yes, I know, the data sucks, but it's the data)
   There's a modified wilcoxon test that addresses this problem but I can't find an implementation (Pratt, J. W. (1959). Remarks on Zeros and Ties in the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Procedures. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 54(287), 655–667. doi:10.1080/01621459.1959.10501526)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can. There are different ways to overcome the tie problem. Look at copula package for some solutions. One way is to use: `copula::pobs(data,tie.method="random")`.

Comment: Copula ia a package in R program. There is another one in Paython.

Comment: I've run a quick simulation, doing blom transform on ranks with ties broken randomly, and it seems that, for pairwise comparisons, p-value on real data is better with spearman correlation than with a pearson run on "my own" blom-transformed data - typically roughly 85th percentile of simulations.  this is not to say multivariate data will behave the same way - stay tuned

Answer (score 0):

[image: Vertical bar shows spearman test result; density is the result of 30 blom-based pearson correlation log(p-values). The statistic is thelog p-value of several tests, added up, ergo lower is better]

Note that spearman p-values are typically at 85th-90th quantile of blom simulations.  Still looking into multivariate predictors, which may benefit from gaussianity.  X-scale: lower is better.  See my last comment above for details.